# How to create a Cname record in DNS registry for Cdn service for app on bluemix

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud, cdn, cname

I am trying to add a cdn service to my Bluemix app. So before using the service, I need to configure the routes, which I did. I am using a trial version, so my app domain will be the normal Bluemix default, i.e. mybluemix.net. When I add the app url and the origin route to the cdn service domains tab, it displays the cname and states

`CName for app improperly configured to ERROR:Resolver get NoAnswer.`

Documentation for the cdn service says:

`"Replace the CNAME target for your domain in your DNS provider record with the CNAME displayed".`

I don't understand this, because my domain is the default trial one provided by Bluemix, i.e. mybluemix.net. So is there any way that I can view the DNS provider and update the Cname? Help me out if you have any idea. Need Help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So your current domain without CDN may look like this (take www.stateless.co for example):

```
dig www.stateless.co +short
79.170.40.170
```

It is pointing to a A record in DNS.

So when you start to use CDN, you will need to do configuration in your CDN provider. After the configuration, you will be provided with a CDN hostname to which you need to point your domain as CNAME (you do it in your DNS service provider side). An existing example:

```
dig www.akamai.com +short
www.akamai.com.edgekey.net.
www.akamai.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net.
e1699.dscc.akamaiedge.net.
104.69.150.163
```

where www.akamai.com is pointing to CNAME www.akamai.com.edgekey.net (www.akamai.com.edgekey.net is the CDN hostname provided by Akamai as a CDN provider). Below are the details:

```
dig www.akamai.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.akamai.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53502
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.akamai.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.akamai.com.     288 IN  CNAME   www.akamai.com.edgekey.net.
www.akamai.com.edgekey.net. 11453 IN    CNAME   www.akamai.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net.
www.akamai.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net. 1424 IN CNAME e1699.dscc.akamaiedge.net.
e1699.dscc.akamaiedge.net. 8    IN  A   104.69.150.163
```